# Passing a variable to a shell command from whitin a gnuplot script

Tags: gnuplot

I need to elaborate quite a few files with a gnuplot script that was given to us by a professor. For this reason i am trying to put this script into a loop to automate this task. In doing so i encountered the following problem:

The script executes some shell commands in the line:

```
`cat sin50hz.csv | tail -n +3 |awk 'BEGIN{firstDone=0; print "r(t) = \\"} {if ((NR%40) == 0) {if(firstDone) print " + \\"; split($0,a,","); printf("%f * k(t%s%f)", a[3], ((a[1]<0)? "+" : "") ,-a[1]); firstDone=1}} END{printf("\n")}' > r_of_t.gp`
```

Where "sin50hz.csv" is the input file and "r_of_t.gp" is a function called later in the script. I need to replace "sin50hz.csv" with a variable in order to change the input file at every iteration but i cannot figure out how to pass a variable of the script to the command.

I tried using `system("cat ".myVar." | tail ...")` but this does not work because of the double quotes inside the awk commands.

Is there any way to do something like what i am trying to do? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are probably many ways.  Here's one. I show it with the desired data files in an array but that's not essential, it just gives something to loop over.

```
# split the command into three pieces
$COMMAND << EOC
cat␣
filename-goes-here
| tail -n +3 |awk 'BEGIN{firstDone=0; print "r(t) = \\"} {if ((NR%40) == 0) {if(firstDone) print " + \\"; split($0,a,","); printf("%f * k(t%s%f)", a[3], ((a[1]<0)? "+" : "") ,-a[1]); firstDone=1}} END{printf("\n")}' > r_of_t.gp
EOC

array file = [ "sin50hz.csv", "sin60hz.csv", "somethingelse.csv" ]

do for [i=1:3] {
    print   $COMMAND[1] . file[i]. $COMMAND[3]
    system( $COMMAND[1] . file[i]. $COMMAND[3] )
}
```

*response to comment:*
The datablock named $COMMAND contains three lines. The first line contains the single word "cat". The second is there only for the purpose of illustration; is it never used.  The third contains the entire rest of the command you want to execute.

I do see one thing that may not be obvious in the answer. There is a required space character after "cat".  I have now indicated this with a ␣ symbol.

I suggest debugging this by adding a `print` statement before the call to `system` so that you can see what the commands look like.
I have modified the answer accordingly.  Once you see what the commands will look like, you can test their behaviour directly on the command line to make sure they do what you want.

Comment: thank you for the response. I tried to do as you say but the code does not seem to work (in particular the script runs fine until i call `system( $COMMAND[1] . file[i]. $COMMAND[3] )` and then it stops as if it ended but without doing what comes after), so i have a couple questions: where you wrote `filename-goes-here` can i put whatever i want or is it a keyword? does the call `system( $COMMAND[1] . file[i]. $COMMAND[3] )` need to be at the end of the script?